# Error con plugin Visual Composer de WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme, wordpress-plugin

He instalado WordPress y el tema 'Hood Theme', el cual una vez instalado pide instalar una serie de plugins, entre ellos el Visual Composer.

Una vez instalado todo, el sitio web funciona, pero el panel de control (wp-admin), no funciona y manda el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 104857600 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 491520 bytes) in /home/miweb/wp-content/plugins/Ultimate_VC_Addons/modules/Ultimate_Team.php on line 367

Esta plantilla de WP ya la tengo instalada en otra carpeta del mismo dominio, y funciona sin problemas. Contacté con el soporte de la plantilla y me dijeron que aumentase los limites de memoria de PHP y WordPress, así que lo hice con los valores que ellos me recomendaron:

En el `wp-config` de Wordpress:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M');
```

En el php.ini (esto me lo configuro directamente mi proveedor de hosting):

```
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 600
max_input_vars = 2000
memory_limit = 512M
```

He comprobado que estos valores están funcionando entrando en miweb/phpinfo.php

Una vez hecho todo lo anterior, el problema persiste, y en el soporte de la plantilla no me arrojan ninguna solución que me funcione. A ver si aquí conseguimos encontrar el fallo.

Y éstas son las versiones que estoy usando:

- Versión de WordPress: 4.7.5
- Versión de PHP: 5.2.17
- Versión de Visual Composer: 4.1+

Comment: Por favor, marca alguna de las respuestas como aceptada para dar por cerrada la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

No es nada recomendable usar la versión de `PHP 5.2.17` para un Wordpress 4.7.5 (te recomiendo actualizar al 4.8 para quitarte las vulnerabilidades que tiene esa versión)

Lo mejor que puedes hacer es tener `PHP 7` o en su defecto `PHP 5.6`, el consumo de memoria sera mucho menor y con ello puede que no necesites ni aumentar el consumo máximo de Wordpress.

En cualquiera de los casos, tienes que tener cuidado con modificar a mano cualquier fichero del nucleo de Wordpress, ya que en cualquier actualizacion del mismo esos valores se van a perder.

Algo no está bien si modificando el `wp-config.php` no se aplican los cambios, ten en cuenta que el propio fichero ya tiene controlado si existen esas definiciones:

```
// Define memory limits.
if ( ! defined( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT' ) ) {
    if ( false === wp_is_ini_value_changeable( 'memory_limit' ) ) {
        define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', $current_limit );
    } elseif ( is_multisite() ) {
        define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M' );
    } else {
        define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '40M' );
    }
}

if ( ! defined( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT' ) ) {
    if ( false === wp_is_ini_value_changeable( 'memory_limit' ) ) {
        define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', $current_limit );
    } elseif ( -1 === $current_limit_int || $current_limit_int > 268435456 /* = 256M */ ) {
        define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', $current_limit );
    } else {
        define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
    }
}
```

Puede que en alguna parte de tu código ya lo tuvieras definido.

Answer (score -1):

**SOLUCIONADO**

Resulta que estaba cambiando la memoria de Wordpress en el wp-config.php general, pero en este caso había que cambiarlo en:

wp-includes/default-constants.php

Cambiando la línea 41 que es:
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '40M' );

Por esta:
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M' );

Saludos y gracias de nuevo.

Comment: No creo que sea una solución correcta. Nunca se debe de modificar el core de Wordpress, ya que se va a sobrescribir en cuanto actualices la versión.

Comment: Es un cambio que sugiere tambien la propia plantilla que utilizo. Pero en parte tienes razon si.

Comment: Si la plantilla te recomienda que hagas ese cambio en el propio core de Wordpress, no es una buena plantilla. Otra cosa es que la plantilla te recomiende el cambio pero el el `functions.php` del tema hijo o en su defecto en el `wp-config`